# Trying to compare two consecutive records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I need help in writing a query that compares two consecutive records.

```
select recordDate 
from SiteHistory 
where siteId = 556145 
  and isRecent = 0 
  and isRunning = 1
order by 
    recordDate DESC
```

Gives me around 2000 rows that looks like this:

```
recordDate
-----------------------
2013-05-08 20:04:23.357
2013-05-08 19:45:26.417
2013-05-08 19:30:24.810 
2013-05-08 19:17:22.843
2013-05-08 19:00:16.017
2013-05-08 18:44:14.230
.....
.....
```

Now I need to compare the date of each row with the next row and count how many times the difference between two consecutive dates is greater than 15mins.
This is what I could come up with so far:

```
;with temp as(
select row_number()over(order by recordDate DESC)as 'row', recordDate 
from SiteHistory 
where siteId = 556145 and isRecent =0 and isRunning=1
)

select COUNT(*) as Count from temp t1
INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.row = t1.row+1
where DATEDIFF(mm,t1.recordDate,t2.recordDate)>15
```

However, this doesn't give me the desired. Please let me know how I can correct this to suit my requirements.

Comment: What is the actual output? Also, does SQL Server have the `lag()` window function?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  And in what way are you not getting the expected results? Show specific examples that demonstrate the required corner cases.

Comment: Like I mentioned I am using SQL server 2008. If you look at the records, there are atleast a few records where the difference between consecutive times is greater 15mins. So I am expecting a count that is atleast greater than 1, but I get a count of 0.
And to my knowledge, I don't think SQL server has the lag() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic of your query is correct, only thing its trying to get date difference in month change it to minutes in

```
datediff(minute, t1.RecordDate, t2.RecordDate) > 15
```

Query:

```
  ;with temp as(
     select row_number()over(order by recordDate DESC)as 'row', recordDate 
     from SiteHistory 
     where siteId = 556145 and isRecent = 0 and isRunning = 1
  )
  select COUNT(*) as Count from temp t1
  INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.row = t1.row+1
  where DATEDIFF(minute, t1.recordDate, t2.recordDate) > 15
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 12 seconds! LOL

Comment: This was actually just test data. I eventually have to change it to hours(HH). I was so busy trying to get the logic right that I dint pay attention to that tiny detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"mm" gives you the date difference in *months*

```
where DATEDIFF(mm,t1.recordDate,t2.recordDate)>15
```

Replace "mm" with "minute"

```
where DATEDIFF(minute,t1.recordDate,t2.recordDate)>15
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is as simple as this:

```
where ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,t1.recordDate,t2.recordDate))>15
```

Comment: Yeah. I was so lost that I put in mm instead of minute. Thank you.